# Passing php variable in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=

```
$_email= $connection-> real_escape_string("abc@yahoo.com"); 

$checkSql  = "SELECT * ";
$checkSql .= "FROM customer_registration";
$checkSql .= "WHERE ";
$checkSql .= "EMAIL=" . $_email ;

$result = $connection-> query($checkSql);
```

What seems to be the error in the SELECT statement in the php/mysql query above  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess what ? The answer was right there, it was that I was just missing `` for Table Name and the field.

```
$checkSql  = "SELECT * ";
$checkSql .= "FROM `customer_registration`";
$checkSql .= "WHERE `EMAIL` = ". "'{$_email}' ";

$result = $connection-> query($checkSql);
```

Part of the answer was here :-

[Error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509026/error-in-your-sql-syntax-check-the-manual-that-corresponds-to-your-mysql-server)

Comment: Space is also required buddy. :) Anyways two solutions after a longtime Good luck. Vote the best answers and Mark right answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$checkSql  = "SELECT * ";
$checkSql .= "FROM customer_registration ";
$checkSql .= "WHERE ";
$checkSql .= "EMAIL LIKE '" . $_email ."'";

$result = $connection-> query($checkSql);
```

In your code you using `EMAIL = ".$_email;` which is wrong at least wrap the $_eamil with single Quotes

```
 $checkSql .= "EMAIL='" . $_email."'" ;
```

[Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57f0a/2)

Comment: `=` and `LIKE` are not the same thing.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE 'abc@yahoo.com'' at line 1
@Fredrik

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Try `EMAIL = '" . $_email ."'";`

Comment: @Gogul
Same Error that I posted above !

Comment: Please share your Table schema

Comment: Hi Space misssing after table name "FROM customer_registration " try my edited code

Comment: @Gogul
Thanks for the input, but I posted the working answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$checkSql .= "Email = \"$_email\"";
```